# How to configure weblogic reconnect policy in Spring JMS connection factory

Tags: java, spring, weblogic, weblogic12c, spring-jms

We lost JMS client connection when weblogic JMS server goes down. It leads re-starting our client managed server to re connect JMS server. 
How to configure weblogic reconnect policy? Below are the application context configuration for connectionFactory and Message listener container.

```
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate" />
    <property name="jndiName" value="jndiName" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="destination" ref="destination0"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener"/>
    <property name="taskExecutor" ref="taskExecutor"/>
    <property name="autoStartup" value="true" />
    <property name="messageSelector" value="RECIPIENT = 'XYZ'"/>
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="10"/>
    <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="50"/>
    <property name="idleTaskExecutionLimit" value="10"/>
    <property name="idleConsumerLimit" value="10"/>
</bean>
```

weblogic 12c
spring 3

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using JNDI, you need to configure it in the JNDI provider.